# Wired connection only works when plugged in before startup

Tags: networking, ethernet, startup, disconnect

When I plug in my ethernet cable before startup, the wired connection works. However, if I boot with the ethernet cable unplugged or turn off the wired connection after startup, I am unable to reconnect to a wired connection. The only way for me to make wired connection work again is to restart my PC with the ethernet cable plugged in. I am running on Ubuntu 20.04 (Windows dual-boot) and have a Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5 14ARE05. The ethernet cable works fine on Windows before and after startup, turning on or off. So I don't think there is anything wrong with the ethernet cable. Connect automatically is checked in Ubuntu's wired settings.

here is what **sudo lshw -C network** shows

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 1c:bf:c0:d8:af:05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822ce driverversion=5.8.0-59-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.19 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:76 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fc700000-fc70ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@4:2.3
       logical name: enx00e04c6cae45
       serial: 00:e0:4c:6c:ae:45
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.11.11 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 ip=192.168.1.28 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

**cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml**

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

**sudo dmidecode -s bios-version**

```
EECN31WW
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for replying. I've edited my post. However, I got this error in terminal "cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory" when trying cat /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: The `lshw` command output doesn't show an ethernet interface. Did you give me all of that output?

Comment: @heynnema sorry, i ran it while disconnected from Ethernet. i edited my post again. ```cat /etc/network/interfaces``` still has the same error.

Comment: You have an USB external ethernet adapter. Is it USB3 (blue USB connector) and what kind of port is it plugged into (USB2/USB3)? What make/model adapter is it? You may have a problem with the USB port powering down. Check your BIOS for a USB power option. The Lenovo site is down for maintenance so I can't check your BIOS version.

Comment: @heynnema I have a Rankie USB Network Adapter, USB 3.0 to RJ45 plugged into a Sabrent 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub. The USB hub is plugged into my laptop's USB 3.0 port. I decided to plug the network adapter directly into my laptop and it worked while the PC was on, without having to restart. It seems the network adapter doesn't work well with the USB hub. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @dollynadolly Does the Sabrent Hub have its own external power supply?

Comment: @heynnema it does not. honestly, i think i will just leave it plugged directly into my laptop because i'm thinking plugging it into the hub takes up too much power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rankie USB Network Adapter, USB 3.0 to RJ45**

**Sabrent 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub**

When the Rankie adapter is plugged into the Sabrent hub, it doesn't work properly. When plugged directly into the laptop USB port it works fine.

The USB hub should be a powered hub (a hub with its own external power supply).

**Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5 14ARE05**

You have BIOS version EECN31WW. The Lenovo web site is down for maintenance so I can't check for a newer BIOS for you. Check later on your own.

**Update #1:**

The Lenovo web site is back online.

There's a newer BIOS available for your computer, version EECN35WW, dated 19 May 2021, and can be downloaded [here](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds543921-bios-update-for-windows-10-64-bit-flex-5-14are05).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your computer.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: thanks for all the assistance!

Comment: @dollynadolly You're very welcome!

Comment: @dollynadolly Please see Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: yes, this is the correct BIOS. thank you!